# Having serialization context when using JsonSerializers

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm serializing a complex tree having a lot of JsonSerializers registered and I'm missing a context that I could use for storing data. For instance, imagine you need to i18n localize nodes in the tree and you have to compose localization keys based on current position in the tree that is being serialized. Any idea how to do that ? JsonGenerator and SerializerProvider doesn't provide anything like that.

```
@Override
public void serialize(TreeSection value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) {
    // MISSING some kinda context here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use `ThreadLocal` for passing such information.

You could also request addition of some limited form of contextual storage at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues -- that sounds like a reasonable request.

Comment: a simple member in the serializer would not do it?

Comment: @Katona: a lot of serializers is taking part in serialization of the tree

Comment: @Sloin indeed, I missed it ... I am not an advanced user of Jackson, but you could share a context (i.e `HashMap`) among your serializers providing them via their constructor. I don't have any problem with `ThreadLocal`s, only that it's intended for different purpose

Comment: This won't work in general because (de)serializers are shared: a single instance is used per type (or for contextual ones, per property), so you need to provide some form of separation. Context objects (`SerializerProvider` for serialization, `DeserializationContext` for deserialization) can work; and you could consider sub-classing those (and factory methods called to create instance) if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the **attributes** with jackson 2.7.3 (not sure about the thread-safety, because I am creating a new mapper each time):

```
public ObjectWriter getWriter() {
   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put("my.msg", "message");
   map.put("my.msg2", "message2");
   return new ObjectMapper().writer().withAttributes(map);
}
```

In the serializer class:

```
@Override
public void serialize(TreeSection value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) {
    String msg = (String) provider.getAttribute("my.msg");
}
```

**Update:**
Not working properly when multiple objects are nested in the serialization. Seems like the attributes are passed only to the first object which is serialized.
Seems to be related to https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1991